# Problema obteniendo precios, request y beautifulsoup

Tags: scraping, beautifulsoup, amazon

Estoy teniendo algunos problemas para obtener la información de los precios de la página de Amazon en el mercado estadounidense, en otros mercados no he tenido ningún problema, pero aquí parece que no me devuelve la información aun utilizando todos los métodos que he encontrado por aquí y por internet...

No sé si a alguien más le ha pasado y me puede ayudar, porque la verdad tengo la sensación de haberlo probado todo: BeautifulSoup me devuelve correctamente cosas tales como el título, los ratings y reviews, que también obtengo fácilmente con la petición mediante request. Pero en cuanto al precio ninguno de los dos parece funcionar, en páginas aleatorias, porque en algunas sí, y comprobé que la estructura del HTML es la misma.

Dejo por aquí el código que intenté (y que me funciona salvo en USA):

```
try:
    if len(soup.select('#priceblock_saleprice')) > 0:

    priceElem = soup.select('#priceblock_saleprice')
    price = priceElem.replace('$', '').replace(',', '.').strip()
    Sellingprice = float(price)
    # #print(type(price))
    # print('Precio venta: ', Sellingprice)

elif len(soup.select('#priceblock_dealprice')) > 0:
    priceElem = soup.select('#priceblock_dealprice')
    priceElem = priceElem[0].getText()
    price = priceElem.replace('$', '').replace(',', '.').strip()
    Sellingprice = float(price)
    #print(type(price))
    #print('Precio venta: ', Sellingprice)

else: 

    priceElem = soup.select('#priceblock_ourprice')      
    print(priceElem)            
    priceElem = priceElem[0].getText()
    price = priceElem.replace('$', '').replace(',', '.').strip()
    Sellingprice = float(price)
    print(type(price))
    print('Precio venta: ', Sellingprice)
```

También probé a llamar directamente a las tablas, por si acaso el problema estaba ahí:

```
    #table = soup.find_all('table', {'class':'a-lineitem'})
    # print(table[0])

    # table = soup.find_all(class_="a-lineitem")
    # verdana = table.select('.a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString')
    # for item in verdana:
    #     print(item.text)
    # for td in soup.find('table', {'class':'a-lineitem'}).find_all('td'):
    #     if '$' in td.text : 
    #         for span in td.find('span').find_all('span') : 
    #             if '$' in span.text : 
    #                 print(span.text.strip())
    # result = []
    # priceElem = soup.select('#priceblock_ourprice')
    td_all = soup.find_all('table')
    fin = soup.select('td' 'span')
    print(fin)
    print(td_all[0].text, len(td_all))
    #print('ESTO: ', table[0], len(table))
```

Todo ello de varias maneras.